# add_image_size for custom logo in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to enable users to upload a custom logo for my wordpress theme:

```
function mytheme_setup() {
    add_theme_support('custom-logo');
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_setup');
```

I have tried implementing `add_image_size` to render the logo at 180x180px with this:

```
add_image_size('mytheme-logo', 180, 180);
add_theme_support('custom-logo', array(
    'size' => 'mytheme-logo'
));
```

To display the logo in my theme, I have used:

```
<?php
    // Display the Custom Logo
    the_custom_logo('mytheme-logo');
    // No Custom Logo, just display the site's name
    if (!has_custom_logo()) {
?>
        <h1 style="text-align:center;"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

So I am able to upload and display the logo now, but it seems that the image is not affected by the `add_image_size`. The image is not resized by wordrpress and this is a problem because it may affect loading time of the website.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, referring directly to a custom image size isn't supported anymore for Custom Logo `add_theme_support()` calls:

> Custom Logo does not support the size argument anymore. Specifying the logo size in individual arguments has the advantage of only creating a special image file for the specific logo used (and not every image uploaded), and providing more parity with how Custom Header works.

*(from [Custom Logo on Make Wordpress Core](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/03/10/custom-logo/))*

However, it's an easy - and arguably superior - fix described above: just add the width and height as arguments instead:

```
add_theme_support('custom-logo', array(
    'width' => 180,
    'height' => 180,
));
```

You can then drop your call to `add_image_size()` completely.

Comment: Thanks. Is this going to resize the image at all or is it just appending markup to the output?

Comment: It should indeed resize the image for you :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me ... I can select a logo but it stays huge (does not resize to 180x180)

Comment: @Bassie Did you upload it after changing the size? If it was uploaded before, see the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin